# Kubernetes Secret Store CSI Driver

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I want to use Kubernetes Secret Store CSI driver to store and encrypt Kubernetes secrets. I want to use the secret values in the Configmap manifest files of some of the pods. How do I do it. Below is a sample configmap in which I want to use the secrets like accountId, auth-token.

````
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: config-cron-cm
  namespace: test
data:
  config.yaml: |
    dateValue:  37
    releaseName: release-name
    version: v0.0.7
    configUrl: <some_url>
    accountId: abcdefg123
    clusterIdentifier: test-cluster
    clusterName: test-cluster
    clusterDomain: AWS
    falcoService: 
      daemonName: release-name-falco
      configMapName: release-name-falco-rules
      namespace: test
    configCron:
      cronJobName: config-cron
      configMapName: config-cron-cm
      namespace: test
    threatService:
      deployName: threat-service
      configMapName: threat-service-cm
      namespace: test
    inventoryService:
      deployName: inventory-service
      configMapName: inventory-service-cm
      namespace: test
    misconfigCron:
      cronJobName: misconfig-cron
      configMapName: misconfig-cron-cm
      namespace: test
    ```
````